# how do I stop pre-build steps in the parent job of a jenkins matrix job?

Tags: matrix, jenkins

Has anyone else noticed that the parent job of a set of matrix builds appears to still do anything before the "Build" section in the configuration?

This means that things like Delete workspace and Source Code Management happen on the node running the parent job, even though I can't see when you would ever want that and how it could be useful.

In particular, when using a custom, shared workspace, this means that the parent job of a matrix can stomp on other jobs that use the same workspace.

Does anyone know why this is? More importantly, how do I stop this happening?